# Cygwin and Tesseract : how generate train file on windows

Tags: cygwin, tesseract

I'm totaly new with Cygwin (and tesseract). I'm trying to create a train file. I follow [this tutorial](http://pretius.com/how-to-prepare-training-files-for-tesseract-ocr-and-improve-characters-recognition/).
I've create a jpg file and try to execute this command :

```
Portekoi@PortekoiOrdi /cygdrive/d/_devs/tesseract-ocr
$ /cygdrive/d/_devs/tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe /cygdrive/d/_Devs/Tesseract-OCR/imgTrain/fra.plaque.exp0.jpg /cygdrive/d/_devs/tesseract-OCR/imgTrain/fra.plaque.exp0 /cygdrive/d/_Devs/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs/batch.nochop makebox
read_params_file: Can't open /cygdrive/d/_Devs/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/tessconfigs/batch.nochop
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica
Error in fopenReadStream: file not found
Error in findFileFormat: image file not found
Error during processing.
ObjectCache(011FAAC8)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 05C6FF48 still has count 1 (id D:\_Devs\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/eng.traineddatapunc-dawg)
ObjectCache(011FAAC8)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 05836638 still has count 1 (id D:\_Devs\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/eng.traineddataword-dawg)
ObjectCache(011FAAC8)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 058366C8 still has count 1 (id D:\_Devs\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/eng.traineddatanumber-dawg)
ObjectCache(011FAAC8)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 061BB088 still has count 1 (id D:\_Devs\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/eng.traineddatabigram-dawg)
ObjectCache(011FAAC8)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 061BB880 still has count 1 (id D:\_Devs\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/eng.traineddatafreq-dawg)
```

But `batch.nochop` is not found (but existing in the good path : `D:\_Devs\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\tessconfigs` )

1. How can I resolve this error?
2. With Cygwin, why I have to specfiy full path (I've add good path on environment variables)

Comment: Why you are not using the cygwin packages for Tesseract ? For training you need the additonal `tesseract-training-util` package.

Comment: When you say good path do you mean a full path?